# Access Magento 1.9.x session in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-1.9

I have installed Magento 1.9.x on the root directory of the server and WordPress installed under blog directory(/blog).

I need to show cart item count and my-account link(if customer is logged in Magento) on the header of the blog(WordPress).

I also tried many available solutions like access customer session outside Magento, but nothing works for me.

```
require_once ("/var/www/magento_pack/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
  echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
else
  echo 'Not logged in';
exit;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it's working perfectly, try instead of the full path using this:

```
<?php
require_once ("../app/Mage.php"); # this
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
  echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
else
  echo 'Not logged in';
exit;?>
```